# how to access the context manager output in python

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have written below script:

```
import sqlite3
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlite3 import Error


class DatabaseManager():

    def __init__(self, repoName, table_name):
        self.dbName = repoName
        self.tableName = table_name
        self.createTables()

    @contextmanager
    def db_connection(self):
        # Wait for max 30 seconds before timing out
        con = sqlite3.connect(self.dbName, timeout=30.0)
        yield con
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    @contextmanager
    def dbFetch(self, sqlExecute):
    
        with self.db_connection() as con:
            cur = con.execute(sqlExecute)
            return cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()


    def createTables(self):
       if self.tableName == "tableName":
            createSQL = "CREATE TABLE  if not exists tableName(source text, domain text, jsonExist text, jsonValue text);"

        with self.db_connection() as con:
            con.execute(createSQL)
```

I would like to access the outcome of dbFetch(`withsql query`), how can I achieve that.N0 matter what I do it's only showing `<contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object at 0x01054CA0>`

```
dbManager = DatabaseManager("dbSchema", "tableName")
dbManager.createTables()

response = dbManager.dbFetch("SELECT count(*) FROM {0} WHERE SOURCE = '{1}' AND DOMAIN = '{2}'; ".format("tableName", Source, Domain)
```

how can I get the outpout of dbFetch?

Comment: You should review the use of the `@contextmanager` decorator. You don't make any use of it here. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager

Comment: Either "dbFetch" shouldn't be decorated as context manager (and "cur" must be closed differently) or it should "yield" its output, not "return".

Comment: yes, I think I shouldn't use the decorator. thanks.